# How to remove emacs 23 related packages and leave installed emacs 24

Tags: apt, emacs

I installed `emacs 24` in `Linux Mint 16`, and want to uninstall `emacs 23`.

I thought `sudo apt-get remove emacs23` is enough, but it was not.
This is my packages list relating `emacs`.

```
$ sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep emacs
emacs                       install
emacs23                     deinstall
emacs23-bin-common              install
emacs23-common                  install
emacs23-common-non-dfsg             install
emacs23-lucid                   install
emacs24                     install
emacs24-bin-common              install
emacs24-common                  install
emacs24-common-non-dfsg             install
emacs24-el                  install
emacsen-common                  install
```

To uninstall `emacs 23`, I tried `$ sudo apt-get remove emacs23*`.
But it will also remove `emacs 24` also.

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  emacs emacs23-bin-common emacs23-common emacs23-common-non-dfsg emacs23-lucid emacs24 emacs24-bin-common emacs24-common emacs24-common-non-dfsg emacs24-el
```

Can't use `*` as a `apt-get` argument? How should I remove `emacs 23` correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to the package manipulation command is a regular expression, not a shell wildcard pattern. So `emacs23*` means any package that contains `emacs2` as a substring (since `3*` matches the empty string).

```
apt-get remove '^emacs23'
```